# Inlined constructors? Explain this behavior[C++]

Tags: c++, inline-method

Consider this code

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

class Dummy {
public:
    Dummy();
};

inline Dummy::Dummy() {
    printf("Wow! :Dummy rocks\n");
}

int main() {
    Dummy d;
}
```

All is good here!

Now I do this modification. I move the declaration of Dummy to "dummy.h".

```
class Dummy {
public:
    Dummy();
};
```

And define the constructor Dummy() as following in "dummy.cpp"

```
#include "dummy.h"
inline Dummy::Dummy() {
    printf("Wow! :Dummy rocks\n");
}
```

And finally, I have my main file as:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdio>
#include "dummy.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Dummy d;
}
```

It compiles fine, but I get a linker error complaining an undefined reference to Dummy::Dummy().

Any insights.

--

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put all inline functions (including methods and constructors/destructors) in a header file, where they are declared.

Though this code should work either way, with `main()` calling the constructor as if the `inline` keyword was not there. Are you sure you are passing object files from both compilation units to the linker?

Comment: yeah.it works with inline keyword removed from the constructor, that clearly implies the linker gets both the object files,
Regarding defining inline methods in header, i see your point, however i wonder hwy it works with other functions and just note the constructor?

Comment: @Neeraj It's prob because those other functions were only used in the same .cpp file as the inlined functions.

Answer (score 2):

You should think how compiling works at C++ and the idea of separate compiling units used at C++ and encapsulation gained using headers and cpp files.

Look here:
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inline-functions.html#faq-9.6

The inline tells the complier that instead of calling the function to "copy - paste" its code at the place of the function call. When you put the inline definition in a CPP file it won't be visible during linking to other compiled units (its in cpp file not in h file) so the compiler understand from the signature placed at the class that there is no-paramter Con's so it won't implement the default one. But the linker can't find the function body cause it is implemnted *inline* at the cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the inline specifier from the your implementation file. If my understanding is correct, you can only inline in a header

Comment: Your understanding is partially correct. For a function to be inlined, its definition must be visible in a compilation unit before it is used (i.e. in a header, with the declaration). But even if it is not, the definition in *another* compilation unit will produce an out-of-line instance of a function, and the first compilation unit will simply call this instance as if the `inline` keyword was not there.

Comment: @slacker: the definition in another compilation unit *might* produce an out-of-line instance. It's unspecified whether it does or not, and code that relies on it is illformed.